# how to write mulitple select statement in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE abc(IN _uid VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(filename)
    FROM    file
    WHERE userid = _uid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(file)
    FROM    fileupload
    WHERE userid = _uid
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

As this my query , As I need two select statement output

but it getting error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 10
```

Comment: _semicolon_ *;* missing after _**where condition**_. add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE abc(IN _uid VARCHAR(15))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     SELECT COUNT(filename)
    ->     FROM    file
    ->     WHERE userid = _uid
    ->     UNION ALL
    ->     SELECT COUNT(file)
    ->     FROM    fileupload
    ->     -- WHERE userid = _uid
    ->     WHERE userid = _uid;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```